htaccess in Windows apache root directory
I am on Windows Server, have installed xampp and "C:/xampp/htdocs/" is my root directory. Under that root directory I have multiple project lets say p1,p2,p3.
Now for specific directory, I have provided access to one of the vendors, which is outside of my network, he is accessing my project using https://example.com/p1/
Vendor IP address has been whitelisted at my firewall, and vendor is accessing https://example.com/p1/ from specific IP only.
Now my issue is vendor can also access project p2,p3 etc. using URL https://example.com/p2/,https://example.com/p3/.
I want to allow only https://example.com/p1/ to vendorI I know I can add htaccess in other project directory p2,p3 to disallow vendor IP. but I have hundreds of project in root directory. So instead of adding htaccess in each project directory, I want to add htaccess in root directory that check if IP is of vendor then allow only /p1/ directory, for other directory it should return 403 forbidden to vendor.
Is this possible to achieve? I did some research online didn't find any solution.

Something like this should work but I haven't tried it
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On        
    SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^ALLOWED_IP_GOES_HERE$" ALIAS_IP    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/p1/ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [L]    
    RewriteCond %{ENV:ALIAS_IP} ^1$
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>


Why would one use mod_rewrite as an ACL when mod_authz_host exist for that and is recommended in the official Apache Access Control documentation?

And why using htaccess which is not recommended by the Apache's own documentation, which suggest to put directives into the main configuration instead?

I guess I am bad, or old, or maybe I have 20 years experience and I dont prioritize a mod with 170 questions in Stackoverflow over a module with 24.778.
